# Lower memory usage when searching for optimal route from one point of matrix to another

Tags: c, shortest-path, dijkstra

I have following problem:

> Tourist wants to create an optimal route for the hike. He has a
> terrain elevation map at a certain scale - an NxM-sized matrix
> containing the elevation values ​​at the corresponding terrain points.
> Tourist wants to make a route from the start point to the end point in
> such a way that the total change in altitude while passing the route
> is minimal. The total change in altitude on the route is the sum of
> the changes in altitude modulo on each segment of the route. For example, if there is a continuous ascent or descent from the starting
> point of the route to the end point, then such a route will be
> optimal.
>
> For simplicity, let's assume that you can only walk along the lines of
> an imaginary grid, i.e. from position (i, j), which is not on the edge
> of the card, you can go to position (i-1, j), (i + 1, j), (i, j-1),
> (i, j + 1). You cannot go beyond the edge of the map.
> On standard input: non-negative integers N, M, N0, M0, N1, M1 are entered. N is the number of rows in the heightmap, M is the number of columns. Point (N0, M0) is the starting point of route, point (N1, M1) is the end point of the route. Point coordinates are numbered starting
> from zero. The points can be the same. It is known that the total
> number of matrix elements is limited to 1,100,000.
> After numbers height map is entered in rows - at first the first line, then
> the second, and so on. Height is a non-negative integer not exceeding
> 10000.
>
> Print to standard output the total change in elevation while
> traversing the optimal route.

I came to conclusion that it's about shortest path in graph and wrote [this](https://ideone.com/tNQSxJ)
But for m=n=1000 program eats too much (~169MiB, mostly heap) memory.
Limits are as following:

> Time limit:   2 s
> Memory limit: 50M
> Stack limit:  64M

I also wrote C++ [program](https://ideone.com/keraVb) doing same thing with `priority_queue`(just to check, problem must be solved in C), but it still needs ~78MiB (mostly heap)

How should I solve this problem (use another algorithm, optimize existing C code or something else)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fit a height value into a 16-bit unsigned int (`uint_16_t`, if using C++11). To store 1.1M of those 2-byte values requires 2.2M of memory. So far so good.

Your code builds an in-memory graph with linked lists and lots of pointers. Your heap-based queue also has a lot of pointers. You can greatly decrease memory usage by relying on a more-efficient representation - for example, you could build an NxM array of elements with

```
  struct Cell {
      uint_32_t distance; // shortest distance from start, initially INF
      uint_16_t height;
      int_16_t parent;    // add this to cell index to find parent; 0 for `none`
  };
```

A cell at `row, col` will be at index `row + N*col` in this array. I strongly recommend building utility methods to find each neighbor, which would return `-1` to indicate "out of bounds" and a direct index otherwise. The difference between two indices would be usable in `parent`.

You can implement a (not very efficient) priority queue in C by calling stdlib's "sort" on an array of node indices, and sorting them by distance. This would cut a lot of additional overhead, as each pointer in your program probably takes 8 bytes (64-bit pointers).

By avoiding a lot of pointers, and using an in-memory description instead of a graph, you should be able to cut down memory consumption to

```
1.1M Cells x 8 bytes/cell                    = 8.8M
1.1M indices in the pq-array x 4 bytes/index = 4.4M
```

For a total of around 16 Mb w/overheads - well under stated limits. If it takes too long, you should use a better queue.

Comment: I [tried](https://ideone.com/Yw7UB2) doing as you suggested. Program eats 34MiB (which is fine I guess), but it outputs incorrect answer. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should post the updated code in a new question, and explain what the output is, what you expected, and what your suspicion for the error is. For starters, why is distance a pointer? Have you tested your queue implementation? Have you tried stepping through a small map first, before trying out larger ones?

Comment: Distance was pointer because of comparison for building binary heap. Queue was definitely implemented wrong, so I [replaced](https://ideone.com/eOw75C) it with *not mine* version. It works better, but still not every time (for input on ideone I expect to see 11, not 100000000)

Comment: Your testcase specifies a `2 3 1 0 0 2` in its first line. The 1st two values are n (rows) and m (cols). The next two specify start at `1,0` and end at `0,2`, but there is no `0,2` coordinate within the map (there is, however, a `2,1`). Hence you return INF, that is, unreachable. Looks right to me.

Comment: Indexation starts from 0. BTW, I found my errors: while condition (should be !bheap_empty(ind)) and getRight ( j<m-1, not n-1).